# Subversion 'unadd'?

Tags: svn

I have a number of files I wish to add to subversion. Instead of taking my time and adding each individual one, I decided to be a smart-arse and do a:

```
svn add *
```

.. which was a mistake. Is there a way I can 'unadd' everything? There's about 7 files I wanted to add... it's now highlighted an extra 500+ auto-generated files I didn't mean to add!

I haven't committed it yet so hopefully there's a way to undo this!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do you have any changes other than the files added? (`svn status` will tell you - modified files will show as `M`, added files as `A` - and `svn diff` will show you the details of any changes). If not, then you can just do:

```
svn revert *
```

But if you **do** have changes other than adds, **that will remove them!**

(Probably worth experimenting on a few files first :-)

Comment: I think you mean svn status, not svn diff.

Comment: @Aif: I meant to mention both, but somehow managed to merge the explanations into one. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 10):

You can use

```
svn rm --keep-local *
```

All files will be kept as is, without revert. And `unadd` for the commit step.

Comment: Won't committing after doing this mean that the file is removed from the remote repository?

Comment: This deleted all my files when running this command (not committed)

Answer (score 8):

```
svn st |grep ^A |cut -c 9- |xargs svn revert
```

To first verify what files will be reverted without modifying anything exclude the last command:

```
svn st |grep ^A |cut -c 9-
```

Piping commands is powerful:

- `svn st` will stat everything
- `grep ^A` will give only lines that start with the letter A for added.
- `cut -c 9-` will get the file name from those lines.
- `xargs svn revert` will run `svn revert` for each file name.

If you're on Windows you'll have to download the [UnxUtils](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/) package or similar, but that's well worth it as it brings in a lot of powerful shell commands.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you only have added new things, just do

```
svn revert *
```

To be safe, make a local copy of your files first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use
[svn revert](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.revert.html) -depth=infinity .

This will allso undo all local changes to you files, so use it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You can use next command:

```
svn revert
```