# SVN ignore - "not under version control"

Tags: svn, version-control

I have a directory structure that looks like:

```
components
  |_ticker
    |_sass-utils
      |_ ..
    |_ticker.css
    |_ticker.sass
    |_ ..
```

There are several files I don't want under SVN version control. *components* is already committed but *ticker* is not yet committed and `svn status` currently states:

```
?       components/ticker
```

If I `cd` into the *ticker* directory then try: `svn propedit svn:ignore .` (which is what I tried from this [SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5374616/997596)) I get the error:

```
svn: E200005: 'components/ticker' is not under version control
```

I believe that once I `svn add components/ticker`, files under `ticker` can no longer be ignored.

So how do I ignore files that are not under version control yet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to ignore a directory with SVN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116074/how-to-ignore-a-directory-with-svn)

Comment: I followed the advice of that answer by doing `svn propedit svn:ignore .` but as stated, I get the `not under version control` error. So something is somehow different in my setup.

Comment: That's because you need to set the "svn:ignore" property on the parent directory, and set it to a value matching the directory you want to ignore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/116131/14660) lays it all out.

The problem you're having is you're going into the directory to be ignored (components/ticker) and trying to set properties.  You're treating svn:ignore as if it acts on the current directory.  svn:ignore is list of *sub-directories* to be ignored.  You need to set the ignore property in the parent directory (components) and give it the sub-directory to ignore (ticker).

```
cd components
svn propset svn:ignore ticker .
```

Comment: Doesn't `propset` only ignore a single pattern? As I want to ignore multiple patterns, shouldn't I do `svn propedit svn:ignore ticker .`? When I do that from *components*, again I get the 'not under vc' error.

Comment: The propedit syntax is `svn propedit <property> <files-whose-props-to-edit>`.  `svn propedit svn:ignore ticker .` says to edit ticker's properties and then components'.   So `svn propedit svn:ignore .` and add "ticker" in the editor.

Comment: Now it's making more sense to me, but I don't want to ignore the whole of 'ticker'. So in propedit I add `ticker/ticker.scss` (also tried just `ticker.scss`) but on `svn status` ticker.scss is still listed with `?`.

Comment: svn:ignore only works for the immediate items in the directory.  If not all of ticker will be ignored, then `svn add ticker`, `svn propedit svn:ignore ticker` and add `ticker.scss`.  I suspect you really want `*.scss`.

Comment: Doing `svn propedit svn:ignore ticker` I again get the 'ticker is not under version control'. Sorry I have no idea why this isn't working.

Comment: What happened when you `svn add ticker`?

Comment: I have now done `svn add ticker` now all files under ticker have been added (including all the ones I'm trying to ignore).

Comment: @Fisu Sorry, it's been a while since I've used svn, I forgot it's recursive. [Unadd the problem files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882898/subversion-unadd).  In the future, `svn add --depth=empty` will stop it from recursing.

Comment: Yes that works, thanks for working it through with me.